# most pythonic way to time a loop

Tags: python, for-loop, timer

So I have a loop which takes a while to run and I wanted to print a rough estimation of the ETA (time required to end), I have written some code to do this but it's quite intricate and I'm sure there must be a cleaner way of doing it, any tip?

my class:

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import sys


class Measure:
    def __init__(self):
        self.initial = None
        self.end = None
        self.average = None

    def start_end(self):
        if self.initial is not None:
            self.end = timer()
        else:
            self.initial = timer()

    def avg(self):
        self.start_end()
        if self.end is not None:
            if self.average is None:
                self.average = round((self.end - self.initial), 3)
            else:
                self.average = round((self.average + (self.end - self.initial)) / 2, 3)
            self.initial = timer()

    def avg_time(self):
        self.avg()
        if self.average is not None:
            sys.stdout.write('\r' + "Avg. Time elapsed: " + str(self.average) + " seconds")

    def how_long(self):
        self.start_end()
        if self.end is not None:
            print("Time elapsed: " + str(round((self.end - self.initial), 3)) + " seconds")
            self.initial = timer()

    def estimated_time(self, length):
        self.avg()
        if self.average is not None:
            x = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=self.average * length)
            sys.stdout.write('\r' + "I still need to work for at least...: " + str(round(self.average * length, 3))
                             + " seconds. Which means I'll be done by: " + x.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"))
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]

Comment: [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html)

Comment: You want to measure how long the loop took, or you want to estimate how long the loop will take?

Comment: @Barmar mainly estimate how long it will take

Comment: You can only do that if you know the time complexity of the code. If it's linear, you can multiply the time of a single iteration by the number of iterations.

Comment: There's no good way of doing that. Wall time depends on _lots_ of things - how busy the CPU is, IO delays, thermal throttling - I would just print the progress: `5/100 iterations done.` If you _really_ want an estimate of the time, record the start time, record the current time at the end of each iteration, and do some math. `expected_time = total_iters * (current_time - start_time) / current_iter` but don't expect it to be accurate. (my math may be off here, so don't trust that equation)

Comment: It'd help to see an example of a loop you want to time, or to have a description of `Measure`'s API.  It doesn't seem like you pass enough information in to this class for it to be able to make a meaningful estimate of anything.  The way Pranav describes it is the way I'd do it (this is also basically how you get "time remaining" estimates on file transfers etc), but you need to know the number of completed iterations relative to the number of expected iterations to be able to calculate that ratio.

Answer (score 1):

You can time any aspect of your code in regards to how long it takes to run, not just a particular chunk of it. But if you want to get just the time taken for the loop itself to compute, you can do something like:

```
import time

starttime= time.time()

**add your loop/other code here**

endtime= time.time()
print("time elapsed:", endtime - starttime)
```

Comment: They want to estimate how long the long loop will take, not report the elapsed time.